Render part of a file in eevee part in cycles
I have a file that needs parts to be renders in EEVEE but some other parts in Cycles, how is best to do this.
Most of the file needs to be rendered in EEVEE, the only part that needs to be rendered using Cycles is a glass texture I created using IOR =  1.330 and  Alpha = 0.216 for this to render as the correct texture it needs to be rendered in Cycles.
This is the bit that needs EEVEE:

And this is the bit that needs cycles:


do 2 renders, use transparency to overlay the 2 images in the Video Sequencer afterwards?

Can you please explain how to do that a bit more, I have never used the video sequencer before.

just add your two strips in the vse (add image sequence or movie). Put the one with alpha on top.

Is it possible for you to send me some screenshots on how to do this?

Could you please show your scene and tell what part needs to be rendered with Eevee and other part needs to be rendered with Cycles? You may need to use masks, depending on the complexity of your scene...

I have edited the question to contain images

There are probably several way, I propose a solution with the Compositor

You can try it with the Compositor: First render your scene with Eevee, and a second time with Cycles, save the image sequences in 2 separate folders. Then in the View Layer panel enable Cryptomatte > Object:

Open the Compositor window, enable Use Nodes and Backdrop, do a render so that you can see the image in the background, create a Mask > Cryptomatte, click on its "+" icon and with the eyedropper click on the window on the background image so that it is selected as object to matte, use the Matte output of the node and plug it as factor into a Color > Mix > Alpha Over, plug the Alpha Over into the Output. Create 2 Input > Image nodes and load your 2 image sequences (Eevee and Cycles), mix then into the Alpha Over node, render in a new folder:


Hello,
I read on another forum post that you can do this by using multiple scenes, should I just combine the two scenes?

WIth my solution you don't need to scenes but it may be another solution, I don't know

The file has no animations, do I still need  to save the render outputs?

You need to do 2 renders, one for Cycles, one for Eevee, then mix the way I show, it's exactly the same
